# how to check hover mouse in one element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm noob in `jQuery` and I want to understand that how to know my mouse is hover in one element when this mouse leave another element.

I write this code :

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li class="conver">1</li>
    <li class="conver">2</li>
    <li class="conver">3</li>
    <li class="conver">4</li>
    <li class="conver">5</li>
</ul>
<div id="center">JSFIDDLE</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('ul').on('mouseenter','li', function () {
        $('#center').fadeIn('fast');

}).on('mouseleave','li', function () {
     //I want when mouse leave this element if mouse doesn't hover on ('#center') 
     //element so hide ('#center') element but if to be hover on it this div keep on
     //and don't hide
        $('#center').stop().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

now tell me about it that how I know when mouse leave `li` element **is** on ('#center') element or **not**!!!

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/JCcYZ/)?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain on the question either, but I've made a fiddle of your current code - what needs to be 'fixed'? http://jsfiddle.net/VFrUt/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
timerId = null;
$('ul').on('mouseenter','li', function () {
        $('#center').fadeIn('fast');

}).on('mouseleave','li', function () {
     //I want when mouse leave this element if mouse doesn't hover on ('#center') 
     //element so hide ('#center') element but if to be hover on it this div keep on
     //and don't hide
     timerId = setTimeout(function(){
                     $('#center').stop().fadeOut('fast');
               }, 500);

});

$('#center').on('mouseenter', function(){
     if(timerId){
        cleatTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = null;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will work. Have in mind that it is a good practice to cache the jquery selected objects. For example $('#center') is used several times in your code.

```
var center = $('#center');
var ul = $('ul');
var isMouseOnCenter = false;
ul.on("mouseenter", function () {
    center.stop().fadeIn('fast');
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    isMouseOnCenter = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!isMouseOnCenter)
            center.stop().fadeOut('fast');
    }, 300);    
});
center.on("mouseenter", function() {
    isMouseOnCenter = true;
});
```

Here is a js fiddle with the code above http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/cWn65/1/

Also there is a little glitch because you attach the event on the *li* tag. Isn't it better to be on the *ul*.